# Display frame-tick labels on top side

Tags: plotting

I am making a standard framed `Plot` and would like the frame tick labels for the horizontal axis to appear on the top frame edge.

I know I can do this by hand using, for example:

```
Plot[x, 
 {x, 0, 5},
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {{{0, ""}, {1, ""}, {2, ""}, {3, ""}, {4, ""}, {5, 
      ""}}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}}
 ]
```

But that is so terribly cumbersome, how can I just make the standard/default frame ticks appear on the top instead of the bottom?

Comment: Unfortunately, graphics in *Mathematica* is just terribly cumbersome. You'll have to get used to it. You can use `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, All}}`, perhaps. Or use `Automatic` instead of `None` and just delete the labels in a drawing program. (That's what I've done before.) Biggest problem is that it does not seem to be possible to retrieve the automatic tick specification (especially the tick lengths) in order to reproduce it.

Comment: OK thanks, I guess 'All' will do for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a hack, but this should work:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, All}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {4, 20}}]
```

[image: imagemargins]

The values for `ImagePadding` are chosen so as to leave no room for the bottom tick labels to be displayed. You can change the margins from `20` to `40` (e.g.) if you need more room to display additional labels. The bottom image margin of `4` is the one that cuts off the undesired labels.

**Edit: a more systematic approach**

The following approach is based on a different idea that will not require any devious cropping of unwanted text. At the same time, it still avoids the need to specify tick marks manually.

To achieve this, I use [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) to emulate the `Automatic` tick placement (I didn't try to get it exactly right, but added some customizability). The ticks are calculated automatically for each plot, and there are versions with and without tick labels: `tickFunction` and `tickFunctionNoLabel`. To avoid having to think about these functions every time you make a plot, I just use `SetOptions` to make `Plot` call them automatically:

```
Clear[tickFunction, tickFunctionNoLabel, gridFunction, divisionFunction]

divisionFunction[xMin_, xMax_] := 
  FindDivisions[{xMin, xMax}, {8, 5}];

gridFunction[xMin_, xMax_] := First[divisionFunction[xMin, xMax]]

Options[tickFunction] = {"MinorLength" -> 0.005, "MajorLength" -> .01,
    "InsideOutside" -> {1, 0}};

tickFunction[xMin_, xMax_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{major, minor},
  {major, minor} = divisionFunction[xMin, xMax];
  Join[Map[{#, #, 
      OptionValue["InsideOutside"] OptionValue["MajorLength"]} &, 
    major], Map[{#, "", 
      OptionValue["InsideOutside"] OptionValue["MinorLength"]} &, 
    Flatten[minor[[All, 2 ;; -2]]]]]
  ]

tickFunctionNoLabel[xMin_, xMax_] := 
 Map[{#[[1]], "", #[[-1]]} &, tickFunction[xMin, xMax]]

SetOptions[Plot, 
  FrameTicks -> 
   {{tickFunction, tickFunctionNoLabel}, {tickFunctionNoLabel, tickFunction}}];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: tickfunction]

As you see, I didn't have to add any options to this `Plot` command, and the frame ticks come out properly.

I added the ability to adjust the lengths of the major and minor ticks as options of the `tickFunction`. Another option is called `"InsideOutside"` which decides how much of the ticks is inside or outside of the frame. By default, it's all inside, specified by an option value `{1,0}`. Here is what it looks like with external ticks:

```
SetOptions[tickFunction, "InsideOutside" -> {0, 1}];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> gridFunction]
```

[image: grid]

For fun, I added a grid to this plot (that's when you really need external ticks, I think). The grid is derived from the same `FindDivisions` that underlies the ticks, as calculated in `divisionFunction`.

In this approach, the placement of the labels is entirely controlled by the order in which you call `tickFunction` or `tickFunctionNoLabel` in the `FrameTicks` option specification.

For example, you can do the following:

```
SetOptions[Plot, 
  FrameTicks -> {{tickFunctionNoLabel, 
     tickFunction}, {tickFunctionNoLabel, tickFunction}}];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: right label]

Finally, an example for different tick lengths, where I also choose to specify the tick functions directly as an option in `Plot`:

```
SetOptions[tickFunction, "InsideOutside" -> {1, 0}, 
  "MajorLength" -> .02, "MinorLength" -> .01];

Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunction, tickFunction}, {tickFunctionNoLabel, 
    tickFunction}}]
```

[image: tick lengths]

To further customize the automatic tick marks, you can also change the parameters of `FindDivisions` in the definition of `divisionFunction`.

Comment: (+1) *Mathematica* has surprisingly many `Tick`-related bugs! :(

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I wasn't expecting it to be so much trouble..