# Is this currently the only way to have the axes and ticks on top of a plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to place my axes on the top and right sides of my plot (as opposed to the more common bottom and left).

I found [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88982/display-frame-tick-labels-on-top-side) from Googling. That's nice, but is that really the best way to do it at the moment? It seems kind of cumbersome for such a simple operation.

Comment: Related: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126245/how-to-generate-vertical-scale-on-both-sides-of-the-plot) and [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126415/how-to-remove-tick-labels-from-only-one-axis-of-a-frame)?

Comment: @YungHummmma - I think the best thing to do if you don't like the solutions for that thread is to offer a bounty for a better solution.

Comment: @JasonB do developers accept bounties? ;)

Comment: @YungHummmma - With all the success they've had with the `PlotTheme` option, it should be suggested to have a theme "LabeledOnTopRight" or something similar

Comment: @YungHummmma You could try this:  `Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,  FrameTicks -> {{Range@5, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, {{0,   Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, None}}]`